# vue3 with vite can't import .ts interface

Tags: vuejs3, vite

edit: similar to [vitejs bug](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2117) but different because I don't reimport.

edit2: i just created a new clean project [vue build tools](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#with-build-tools) and just selected the typescript features and it still doesn't work.

edit3: [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-vid96b?file=src/App.vue)

I can't import the following `interface`:

```
export interface Topic {
   title: string;
   description: string;
}
```

in `App.vue`:

```
import { Topic } from "@/models/topic";

The requested module '/src/models/topic.ts' does not provide an export named 'Topic'
```

What is happening here? I followed this guide [vue build tools](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#with-build-tools)

Comment: That demo link does not demonstrate the problem, as `App.vue` is not even using TypeScript (which causes an unrelated compiler error). Can you update the demo so that it actually reproduces the original problem in question?

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems here:

1 - In the script tag you forgot to tell vue that you want to use TS:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
```

2 - The way to import a type or interfaces should be as follow:

```
import type { Topic } from './models/topic'
```